# Extend's Constructor can't find config parm?

Tags: extjs4.2

In the extjs4.2;

In the follow code，It's show "Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined " on chrome's console.

that maybe the problem in
Vehicle.prototype.constructor.call(this,config);
but, why it can't pass the config.

why?
can someone help me ?

thank .

```
function Vehicle(config){
   this.x=config.x;
   this.y=config.y;
}

Vehicle.prototype.move=function(dx,dy){
   this.x +=dx;
   this.y +=dy;
};

Vehicle.prototype.toString=function(){
   return "point:"+x+","+y;
};

var Car=Ext.extend(Vehicle,{  
     constructor:function(){  
       Vehicle.prototype.constructor.call(this,config);
       this.color=config.color;
     },move:function(dx){  
         this.x=dx;
     },toString:function(){
        var str="Car is "+ this.x + " miles away from the origial position.";
        str +=" this car is :"+this.colr;
        return str;
     }

});

var carConfig={
    x:10,
    y:0,
    color:"white"
};

var car= new Car(carConfig);
car.move(150);
console.info(car.toString());
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Why are you writing classes like this? Ext provides a whole class system to abstract a lot of this away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are missing is the parameter to your constructor function.

I made a fiddle to show ya: http://jsfiddle.net/edhedges/JkPLL/

```
function Vehicle(config){
   this.x=config.x;
   this.y=config.y;
}

Vehicle.prototype.move=function(dx,dy){
   this.x +=dx;
   this.y +=dy;
};

Vehicle.prototype.toString=function(){
   return "point:"+x+","+y;
};

var Car=Ext.extend(Vehicle,{  
     constructor:function(config){ // missing config here
       Vehicle.prototype.constructor.call(this,config);
       this.color=config.color;
     },move:function(dx){  
         this.x=dx;
     },toString:function(){
        var str="Car is "+ this.x + " miles away from the origial position.";
        str +=" this car is :"+this.colr;
        return str;
     }

});

var carConfig={
    x:10,
    y:0,
    color:"white"
};

var car= new Car(carConfig);
car.move(150);
console.info(car.toString());
```

Comment: Dear edhedges：Thx for your help! I get It

Comment: @wayout No problem. You may want to take into account what Evan Tromboli said in his comment on your question. I've never used Ext JS so I don't know best practices, but he seems to think there are better ways to structure your code.